# Nodejs, Electron nightmare is not defined when it's installed?

Tags: node.js, electron

I've installed Nightmare via NPM this is my code:

```
var jquery = require('jquery')
var nightmare = require('nightmare')
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });

$( "#test" ).addEventListener('click',() => {
    nightmare
        .goto('http://akhiljose.me/master/paste/')
        .type('.form-control', 'Test')
        .type('input[type=test]', 'nightmare_test')
        .click('input[type=submit]')
        .wait(7000)
        .evaluate(function () {
        return document.querySelector('pre').innerText;
        })
        .end()
        .then(function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        })
        .cat(function (error) {
        console.error('Search failed:', error);
        })});
```

However console logs:

```
C:\Users\ninja_000\Desktop\clu-gen\index.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: Nightmare is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ninja_000\Desktop\clu-gen\index.js:3:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ninja_000\Desktop\clu-gen\index.js:22:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:642:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:653:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:561:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:504:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:496:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:586:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at file:///C:/Users/ninja_000/Desktop/clu-gen/index.html:12:5
```

I'm very new to nodejs what is causing this error? Am I do something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling an undefined variable.

```
var jquery = require('jquery')
var nightmare = require('nightmare')
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });
```

The second line declares a variable `nightmare` but the next line you are calling `Nightmare`. Make the second line uppercase.

```
var jquery = require('jquery')
var Nightmare = require('nightmare')
var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });
```

You can see from the second line of the stack trace:

```
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ninja_000\Desktop\clu-gen\index.js:3:17)
```

Line 3:17, there is an uncaught `ReferenceError: Nightmare`. This make sense because `Nightmare` is not defined, so nodejs cannot find it. The line numbers in the stack trace are useful to pinpoint where in the code the error is occurring. You can also use a linter which will show an error for trying to use an undefined variable. Something like `eslint`.

Answer (score 0):

Should've defined as Nightmare not nightmare